# Django 1.8 OperationalError: No such column

Tags: django, django-models, django-database, django-migrations, django-1.8

I just wanted to add a field on a model.

```
class Categories(models.Model):
    #this IDUnique = models.IntegerField(max_length=11, blank=True, null=True)
    IDParent = models.IntegerField(max_length=11, blank=True, null=True)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=False)
```

When I try migrate:

```
    Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: formtools, social_auth, crispy_forms, django_comments
  Apply all migrations: sessions, admin, sites, auth, appname, contenttypes
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
  Installing custom SQL...
  Installing indexes...
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

deleted and migrated again and tried sqlmigrate

```
   BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE "appname_category__new" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "IDParent" integer NULL, "Name" varchar(45) NOT NULL, "IDUnique" integer NULL);
INSERT INTO "appname_category__new" ("Name", "id", "IDParent") SELECT "Name", "id", "IDParent" FROM "appname_category";
DROP TABLE "appname_category";
ALTER TABLE "appname_category__new" RENAME TO "appname_category";

COMMIT;
```

And still says

```
no such column: onlinemarket_categories.IDUnique
```

Thank you

Comment: Django 1.8 has not been released. Stick with 1.7.x for now.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you running `sqlmigrate`? The correct command to run migrations is just `migrate`.

`sqlmigrate` simply prints the SQL that would be executed in a migration, as [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/#the-commands) shows.

Comment: yes but it shows when you create table successfully. when i try migrate it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to run `python manage.py makemigrations` and after that `python manage.py migrate` or `python manage.py syncdb`?

Comment: yes I did, I found the problem. Django 1.8 was beta. I switched to 1.7 teşekkürler